# Using the output of Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

```
β = 100;
v0 = 5*10^-9;

 Reduce[{a/b^2 + 1/a == (2 b)/a^2 + 2/3 β b && (3 v0)/(
      4 π a^2) < b < (3 v0)/(2 π a^2)}, a, Reals] // N
```

This gives me the output

```
0.00106077 < b < 0.00133648 && 
 a == Root[-6 b^3 + 3 b^2 #1 - 200 b^3 #1^2 + 3 #1^3 &, 1]
```

I would like to put the minimum and miximum values of b into bmin and bmax and set a function a(b) i.e.

```
bmin=0.00106077 
bmax=0.00133648 
a[b_]:=Root[-6 b^3 + 3 b^2 #1 - 200 b^3 #1^2 + 3 #1^3 &, 1]
```

The thing is I don't want to copy and paste like this because next, I want to be using manipulate to change the values of beta and v0 and I want bmin, bmax, a[b_] to change accordingly.

Comment: It won't be hard to do if the output is always in the form `b1 < b < b2 && a == a0`.  Do you know it will always be that way?  Or might there be cases where `b` may lie in multiple intervals or `a` have multiple values?

Comment: Yes as far as I tried using Manipulate to set the range of beta and v they were all in that form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might approach the problem something like this.

There exists a function [`ToRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRules.html) that converts some `Reduce` output but it doesn't know what to do with inequalities.  Disregarding open vs closed intervals we can create a replacement rule to transform these inequalities into [`Interval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) expressions:

```
ineqToIntv = HoldPattern[
  Inequality[m_, Less | LessEqual, s_Symbol, Less | LessEqual, M_] | 
  Inequality[M_, Greater | GreaterEqual, s_Symbol, Greater | GreaterEqual, m_]] :>
    (s == Interval[{m, M}]);
```

Now:

```
β = 100;
v0 = 5*10^-9;

sol = Reduce[{a/b^2 + 1/a == (2 b)/a^2 + 2/3 β b && (3 v0)/(4 π a^2) < 
      b < (3 v0)/(2 π a^2)}, a, Reals] // N;

rules = sol /. ineqToIntv // ToRules
```

> ```
> {b -> Interval[{0.00106077, 0.00133648}], 
>  a -> Root[-6 b^3 + 3 b^2 #1 - 200 b^3 #1^2 + 3 #1^3 &, 1]}
> ```

I recommend against defining `a` since it can conflict with the lines above, so I shall use `afn` instead:

```
afn[b_] = a /. rules
{bmin, bmax} = First[b /. rules];

afn[bmin]
afn[bmax]
```

> ```
> 0.00106079
>
> 0.00133652
> ```

In this case `Interval` might be seen as an inconvenience as it simply gets stripped with `First`, but in other cases it may be useful as arithmetic will operate over the expression, e.g.

```
b^-1 /. rules
```

> ```
> Interval[{748.235, 942.71}]
> ```

Comment: What is Inequality[]? This answer is from 2017 so it is not a recent addition, but I don't find it in MMA 11. (And thanks, I used the idea to do similarly for single sided inequalities) What can one do if one needs pure ">" and *open* intervals though?

Answer (score 2):

This will get the desired expressions:

```
β = 100;
v0 = 5*10^-9;

red = Reduce[{a/b^2 + 1/a == (2 b)/a^2 + 
       2/3 β b && (3 v0)/(4 π a^2) < b < (3 v0)/(2 π a^2)}, a, Reals];

N[red] /. {HoldPattern[And[_[b1_, ___, b2_], a == a0_]] :> {a0, {b1, b2}}}
(*  {Root[-6 b^3 + 3 b^2 #1 - 200 b^3 #1^2 + 3 #1^3 &, 1], {0.00106077, 0.00133648}}  *)
```

As for defining the function `a`, I would rather not have `a` be both a variable and a function.  To evaluate `a` at `b == b0`, use `a /. b -> b0`.  Or define

```
a[b0_] := a /. b -> b0
```